# Mapping mixed case Parquet to Snowflake with ADF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

Trying to solve an issue with mapping mixed case fields in a Parquet file to Snowflake, as it stores column names in uppercase.

I'm using Azure Data Factory's copy activity to load a Parquet file to Snowflake. For example, my parquet schema is (ID, CustomerName, CustomerType). When loading to Snowflake, I get the ID column populated, but nothing in CustomerName/CustomerType.

Keeping in mind that my source casing can unexpectedly change (e.g. CustomerName -> customername), has anyone seen and solved this issue before?

Comment: Have you looked in schema drift? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-schema-drift

Answer (score 1):

If your parquet is already in blob, you should be able to copy them directly into a Snowflake table with the

```
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE
```

copy option.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Example:

```
copy into example_table from @example_stage/table_folder/
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE -- match parquet column names to snowflake table column names
PATTERN = '.*parquet' -- optional, pattern to only copy files that end in "parquet"
PURGE = TRUE -- optional, will delete successfully copied files from blob (if privlaged to do so)
;
```

ADF now has the script activity so you can orchestrate this there.

https://medium.com/@chuang.zhu/seamless-migration-to-snowflake-using-adf-script-activity-schema-detection-25475ea86a09

Side Note: Snowflake has schema detection for parquet, so you can even generate tables directly from your parquet files as well.

Comment: It is also possible to provide MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME as importSettings option.

Comment: Great call out @LukaszSzozda

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this feature. Unfortunately does not look compatible with the Copy Activity and would need to through something separate like a Script Activity as mentioned. I tried this option through the additional copy options and got an error along the lines of it not being compatible with a copy transform.

Answer (score 0):

[Snowflake as sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-snowflake?tabs=data-factory#snowflake-as-sink):

> Snowflake connector utilizes Snowflake’s COPY into [table] command to achieve the best performance. It supports writing data to Snowflake on Azure.
>
> | Property | Description | Required |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | importSettings | Advanced settings used to write data into Snowflake. You can configure the ones supported by the COPY into command that the service will pass through when you invoke the statement. | No |

Option: `MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE`